# Hide Existing Panel Server Side

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to hide a panel based on values, using server side code.

- The form feeds from an Object Datasource
- The panel resides inside the form
- The Object Datasource triggers the CustomerDataSource_Selected sub

[image: Web form Code]

Server Side Code does execute

```vb
Public Sub CustomerDataSource_Selected(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs)
    Dim DisplayPanel As Boolean
    DisplayPanel = False
    If e.ReturnValue IsNot Nothing Then
        If e.ReturnValue(0).x1 < e.ReturnValue(0).x2 Then
            DisplayPanel = True
        End If
    End If

    Dim FPanel As Panel = CType(FormView.FindControl("FuturePanel"), Panel)
    FPanel.Visible = DisplayPanel 'here is the problem...
End Sub
```

I get the exception below because the sub "CustomerDataSource_Selected" is invoked by the ObjectDataSource, which has no access to the form's Control Collections in the code above :

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

How can I hide the panel using the current sub, which needs access to the control collection?

Remember that the sub is invoked from the ObjectDataSource?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
Dim FPanel As Panel = CType(FormView.FindControl("FuturePanel"), Panel)
```

Is not getting the control.  (FPanel == Null)

Try this...

```
Dim FPanel As Panel = CType(FormView1.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("FuturePanel"), Panel)
```